# Young adult book with a heroine who in the future is worshipped as a goddess

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read this about 8 years ago, but I think I got the book from a public library so it could have been published earlier. It was in Britain, so I assume a British author. It was probably from the "Young Adult" section.

The plot takes place in two time periods, the first time period is in the near future, some calamity is wiping out most of humanity, and the heroine (a teenage girl) is the only survivor of a plane that crashes in a remote region. The story tells of her struggle to survive, and how she documents her difficulties and achievements in notebooks.

The second part of the plot is set in the far future, maybe a thousand years after the event that nearly caused humans to go extinct. In the future the girl is revered as a goddess, or at least a prophet, and the people of that time scrutinize her notebooks, sometimes drawing entirely the wrong conclusion from some casual remark, or finding items that she had used and treating them as holy relics. The narrative switches back and forth between these two time periods, so you'd see some event in the girls real life, and then how the future people (mis)interpret it.

I think the "message" was to "remember that the great people from the past were human beings."

I think the cover was orange.

It's not "An Accidental Goddess" or "Goddess in the Machine" In these books, the heroine time-travels or cryo-sleeps to the future, to find that she is considered a goddess. The heroine in this story remains in our time, and the contrast is in the matter of fact nature of her real life, with the spiritual interpretations of the future people.

I've been through the list for story identification, and this is all that I can remember.

Comment: There are some similarities with _[Summer of Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_of_Love_(novel))_ by Lisa Mason, but there's no calamity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't match all the plot points, but the idea of the writings of a young woman survivor of an apocalyptic event becoming the gospels of a future religion, told in both timelines, matches [*Half Lives*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1579135) (2013) by Sara Grant.

[image: Cover of "Half Lives" showing a woman's silhouette in yellow and orange tones against a black backgroun]

The book's blurb says:

> NOW: Icie's parents gave her $10,000 in cash, a map of a top-secret bunker, and instructions to get there by any means necessary. They have news of an imminent viral attack and know that the bunker is Icie's only hope for survival. She and three other teens live locked away for months, not knowing what's happening in the outside world or who has survived. Then one day, Icie discovers a shocking secret deep in the bunker. Are they really safe there after all?
>
> THEN: Generations in the future, the world has changed, and a mysterious cult worships the very mountain where Icie's secret bunker was built. The people never leave the mountain, they're ruled by Beckett, a teenager...and they have surprising ties to Icie.
>
> Icie and Beckett must both fight to survive while protecting a secret that could destroy their civilizations.

Quoting from a [review on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/633392588):

> Teenager phrases of rebellion and songs become everyday greetings & prayers. With the higher power guiding them called the great I AM. At one point in the Isis timeline, **Ici etches her initials onto trees. Isis Anne Murrey (IAM), & I realised she is the great I AM.** Yet she was just a girl who lost everything but still found a way to survive and start a new society. When Beckett discovers her diary, telling the true events that led to Forreal’s creation, he has to decide whether to reveal the truth or allow his family to continue believing in I AM.

The book starts with a panicked plane flight out of a doomed Washington, DC, but it doesn't crash, it lands safely in Phoenix, from which begins an adventure to reach the bunker near Las Vegas.